# Google AppEngine webapp2: No module named pkg_resources error when importing bigquery

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am devolving a web engine app, and want to connect to Google bigquery.
Everything works fine until I type the following:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

[image]

If I put this line in a .py file and compile it, it works perfectly fine. It is not working in the main.py in my app folder. My site-package has pkg_resources folder in it, I don't see why.
Below are the error message:

[image]

Here is the app.yaml file:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post text as images. Instead copy-paste and format it accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Did you vendor in the client library into your app? https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/bigquery/v2#appengine

Comment: No, I did not. Do I need to even if I have installed them via pip?

Comment: installed them where?

Comment: local machine... Do you suggest that I copy the folder "bigquery" from site-package to MyAPP/lib?

Comment: No, copying might not cut it. Follow the procedure. GAE has no idea what's on your local computer. And the local devserver attempts to emulate that. Everything need to be in the app code you're deploying on GAE. That's why the method is being referred as "vendoring into your app".

Comment: I followed the procedures and install bigquery.  Right now I have some new folders in MyAPP/lib, however, I still got the same error. No module named pkg_resources. Which package shall i be installing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137106/discussion-between-dan-cornilescu-and-tao).

Comment: @DanCornilescu Where does one even find pkg_resources so you can even vendor it into the app?

Comment: @Praxiteles you vendor bigquery, not pkg_resources, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traceback indicates you're running bigquery code from your local machine library, not from the app's library.

You need to vendor the library into your application. From the [App Engine](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/bigquery/v2#appengine) specific BigQuery API Client Library for Python instructions:

> Because the Python client libraries are not installed in the [App
>   Engine Python runtime environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/), they must be [vendored into
>   your application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#vendoring) just like third-party libraries.

Comment: Thank you. Work like a charm.

Comment: What would the traceback look like if it were running bigquery code from the app's library?

Comment: The path of the `__init__.py` file would have included the app dir and not the system's `site-packages` dir