# Import Error: No module named google.cloud when I tried to import the BigQuery

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-app-engine-python

When I try to use this statement in Google App Engine

```
from google.cloud import big query
```

It produces the error `No Module Named Cloud` but it runs fine and update the BigQuery tables if I run it from local machine.

I want to make it a cron job on Google App Engine but this is not working.

Environment:
I am in the Standard Environment and its Python 2.7. I am not running the App Engine SDK development Server, I am deploying the App live.

My Code is:

```
 import time
 import uuid
 from google.cloud import bigquery
 client = bigquery.Client()
 jobid = "jid" + str(uuid.uuid4())
 query = "Select * FROM Table"
 job = client.run_async_query(jobid, query)
```

When I run the Command `gcloud app browse`, it opens a Browser and gives the following error:

> ```
> Error: Server Error 
> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.[![Error Trace][1]][1]
> ```
>
> [image]

Comment: Potentially relevant (you may have installed it on the local system, but not in your app): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570771/google-appengine-webapp2-no-module-named-pkg-resources-error-when-importing-big/42571561#42571561

Comment: Could you provide some more information about your AppEngine setup? Are you in the flexible or standard environment? What does your config file look like? When you test it locally, are you running the app directly or via the AppEngine SDK development server?

Comment: Hi @ChrisThompson i am in the Standard Environment and its Python 2.7. its the same file i have not changed it when i run it locally. I am not running the App Engine SDK development Server I am deploying the App live.

Comment: Hi @DanCornilescu I have looked at that post and i have installed the libraries over there as well but still its giving me the same error

Comment: Show the exact traceback and the relevant code. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I do not see any **trace backs** its open in the Browser and give the following error Error: Server Error
**The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.**

Comment: @DanCornilescu Sorry if i am missing something but  I do not see any **trace backs** its open in the Browser and give the following error 
**The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.**

Comment: The 'No Module Named Cloud' message is usually close to a traceback. For the `Server Error` check the app logs on the developer console.

Comment: @DanCornilescu Thanks I have added the Image of Error Trace and Edited the Question to include the Image

Comment: That code (which appears to match your `main.py` file, is this correct?) looks like standalone script code, not standard GAE app code. Check out a basic GAE app code here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/quickstart#hello_world_code_review

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139530/discussion-between-dan-cornilescu-and-qaisar-tariq).

Comment: Are you still having this issue? What do you mean by deploying the App live while you're not running the App Engine SDK Dev Server?

Answer (score 1):

The reason could be that `App Engine Standard Environment` does not support `big-query` client library yet. I come across this issue. [Check Here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/1102). And there are more helpful discussions in this [cord](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/1102). You probably can find a solution here.

**Update**

Thanks for your comments and suggests. To improve the previous post, here is some additional information. Since the `big-query client library` is not supported in `App Engine Standard Environment`, a way to communicate with `big-query service` is to use the `googleapiclient`.

To clarify that, here are the procedures to use `googleapiclient`.

1. Import modules from `Oauth2client` and `googleapiclient`:

   ```
   from googleapiclient.discovery import build
   from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
   ```
2. Authenticate and build service:

   ```
   build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=GoogleCredentials.get_application_default(), cache_discovery=False)
   ```
3. Pass your job: A streaming example is used here.

   ```
   row_to_stream = {'keys':keys, 'f1':row['f1'], 'f2':row['f2'], 'ctr':row['ctr'], 'position':row['position']}                    
   insert_all_data = {
    "kind": "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest",
    "skipInvaliedRows": True,
    "ignoreUnknownValues": True,
    'rows':[{
                   'insertId': str(uuid.uuid4()),
                   'json': row_to_stream,
               }]
    }

    build('bigquery', 'v2', cache_discovery=False).tabledata().insertAll(
    projectId=projectid,
    datasetId=dataset_id,
    tableId=tableid,
    body=insert_all_data).execute(num_retries=5)
   ```

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Welcome to [so]! There is one more step to change this from an "almost" answer to a great answer: please include the relevant information from the issue report [directly in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49823870/edit). The issue could be deleted at any time, which would take away the value of your current post to future readers.

Comment: If you can include a specific strategy that will (or could) fix the asker's problem, then even better!

Comment: It is confusing. If the library is still not supported, why they include examples in the docs? I guess the library can be used from a Google Compute Engine VM.